# How can I add an equation formula to my question/answer/comment?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

Is there an embeded tool for that in this site?

Unless I missed a very obvious link, there is no much information on how to do that.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use [MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/index.html) markup for embedding LaTeX into answers. See [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for some information. If you still have questions, come ask on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics).